# Softlink on directories not working

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have a hidden folder names /var/bodo/.applications, it is occupying most of the space, I want to create a symbolic link to this /var/bodo/.applications folder in another filesystem  /fblaw/bodo-applications/ folder. I have tried the below command

`ln -sf "/fblaw/bodo-applications" "/var/bodo/.applications"`. It is creating a link inside /var/bodo/.applications folder.

I want link as `.application  -> /fblaw/bodo-applications`

Where am I going wrong?

Please suggest.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38094453/10765659

Comment: You’ve got the order wrong.  You want `bodo-applications -> /var/bodo/.applications`, so you want to say ``ln -s /var/bodo/.applications /fblaw/bodo-applications``.  (You don’t need to put filenames in quotes if they are simple strings with no special characters.)

Comment: See [Direction of a symlink](https://superuser.com/questions/522287/direction-of-a-symlink).